# Evaluating the integral $\int_0^a\tfrac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(a-x)}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $[0,a]$ where $a>0$ and $f(x) + f(a-x) \neq 0$ on $[0,a]$. Evaluate the integral 
>   $$\int_0^a\dfrac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(a-x)}\,dx.$$

I am having trouble with this problem. So far, I have got that 
$$\int_0^a \dfrac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(a-x)} = \int_0^a \dfrac{f(a-x)}{f(x)+f(a-x)},$$
but I don't know how to relate these two integrals in a way that will help me figure out the problem. Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: Add them together?

Answer (score 3):

Converting my comment into an answer, note that you have already proven the following (Which is the tougher part of this problem):
$$I=\int_0^a \frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(a-x)}~dx=\int_0^a \frac{f(a-x)}{f(x)+f(a-x)}~dx$$
Therefore, it follows that:
$$\begin{align}2I&=\int_0^a \frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(a-x)}~dx+\int_0^a \frac{f(a-x)}{f(x)+f(a-x)}~dx\\&=\int_0^a \frac{f(x)+f(a-x)}{f(x)+f(a-x)}~dx\\&=\int_0^a 1~dx \end{align}$$
Where we have used the linearity of the integral. I suppose you know how to continue.